# I am getting " runtime error 91 " while using this code in VBA excel "" .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow + 1 ""

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

it is the code for submit button .

[image: 1]

I was creating a user form and a got run-time error 91

the details should be stored in the database sheet.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/17017616 and then update your question.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image. And please tell us the exact error message, not everyone knows all error codes by heart. And also tell us the row that throws that message.

Comment: Does `iRow = 0` when it errors?

Answer (score 0):

1. edit the iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A]  to: iRow = Counta(Database!A:A)
2. Maybe at begining the A:A is empty and iRow takes a value of 0. To avoid an error use .offset(row, col) where the zero is valid for the row and col.

   Sub submit()
   Dim iRow
   ...

   ```
    iRow = Counta(Database!A:A)
    With sh.cells(1,1)
      .offset(iRow, 0) = iRow+1
      .offset(iRow, 1) = UserForm.txtRol.Value
      ....
    end with
   ```

   End sub